# What methods are there to simulate microscopic cracking of materials?

Tags: reference-request, macroscopic-materials

When a material forms a crack (say, for example, a disk that is getting old, or a fresh bread where force is applied to), on the microscopic/atomic level, atomic bonds break and forces are overcome. What computational methods are there to simulate such behaviour?

Comment: +1. You are so close to fulfilling commitment! 5 more questions or answers: https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/208048/bernhardwebstudio However there's only 1 day left, do you think you can try it, please? :)

Answer (score 8):

The package [LAMMPS](https://lammps.sandia.gov/index.html), that implements Molecular Dynamics, has an example of a crack propagating in a 2D solid. [Here](https://lammps.sandia.gov/inputs/in.crack.txt) is the input they used. A complete mpeg video of the result can be downloaded by clicking [here](https://lammps.sandia.gov/movies/crack.mpg), which shows the crack propagation.

[image]